# Can we usefully characterize those rings whose every non-zero prime ideal is maximal?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

(All my rings are commutative and unital.)

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249027/if-every-prime-ideal-is-maximal-what-can-we-say-about-the-ring/249049?noredirect=1#comment3059338_249049) the following question is asked:

> Suppose $R$ is a ring and every prime ideal of $R$ is also a maximal
>   ideal of $R$. Then what can we say about the ring $R$?

Awesome, awesome question. However, the requirement that $\{0\}$ is maximal if it is prime is very strong. In particular, since $\{0_R\}$ is a prime ideal whenever $R$ is an integral domain, hence every integral domain satisfying the above condition will automatically be a field; this means, in particular, that $\mathbb{Z}$ does not satisfy the condition under question (which is a real shame). So, lets weaken it.

> **Question.** Can we usefully characterize those rings whose every non-zero prime ideal is maximal?

I know that every PID has this property, and that [this characterizes the PID's among the UFD's.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78006/prove-that-a-ufd-is-a-pid-if-and-only-if-every-nonzero-prime-ideal-is-maximal?rq=1)

Comment: So I assume you are here really interested in the case where $R$ is a domain (as otherwise we are just back in that other question).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, true; if $R$ fails to be a domain then we already have an answer to this question. But I'll leave it to the answer-writers whether or not to include this assumption, and if so, where to include it, and for which results. Hopefully, this encourages people to give cleaner, more self-contained answers. But you're right, of course.

Comment: Ohh, I should probably also mention that all Dedekind domains in fact have this property, extending the PID example, but I have no idea how "common" other examples might be.

Comment: There is probably a good supply of interesting domains with Krull dimension 1 even beyond Dedekind domains, but I guess a characterization is not really possible...