# why zero dimensional reduced ring are Von Neumann Regular?

Tags: ring-theory, krull-dimension

i know that commutative VNR are zero dimensional and reduced.But i cant see the converse inclusion.can anyone help me?

Comment: if $R$ is reduced then $x^n$ is not zero for any positive integer $n$.so we can write $x^n=xx^{n-2}x$, and say $x^{n}$ is regular.but i cant see how i can say $x$ is regular foer every $x$ in $R$.And i dint use that $R$ is zero dimensional.

Comment: and on the other way, if $R$ is zero dimensional then every prime maximal and $Nil(R)=Rad(R)$,and since it is reduced $Nil(R)=0=Rad(R)$.So intersection of maximals is zero.Can i write $R$ as a direct sum of these maximal ideals?can i say these sum is finite?if i can,then $R$ is seisimple,and hence VNR.

Comment: [Also related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/629307/29335)